# How to inject SP via Dagger 2.11 with Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

I'm using Dagger 2 with Kotlin. All works fine, but when I'm trying to Inject SharedPreferences to Activity my project doen't even creating.
Gradle Console says:

> di\AppComponent.java:6: error:
>   [dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T)]
>   android.content.SharedPreferences is not nullable, but is being
>   provided by @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable
>   @android.support.annotation.Nullable @Singleton @Provides
>   android.content.SharedPreferences
>   myapp.di.Modules.SharedPrefModule.providePreferences(android.content.Context)
>   e:
>
> e: public abstract interface AppComponent { e:                 ^ e:
>   at:     android.content.SharedPreferences is injected at e:
>   myapp.mvp.StartScreen.StartActivity.sharedPref e:
>   myapp.mvp.StartScreen.StartActivity is injected at e:
>   dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(arg0) e:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to analyze:
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.diagnostic.KaptError: Error while
>   annotation processing

SharedPreferencesModule:

```
    @Module
class SharedPrefModule{

    @Provides
    @Singleton
     fun providePreferences (context : Context): SharedPreferences? {
        return context.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFERENCES_SETTINGS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    }
}
```

AppComponent:

```
    @Singleton
@Component(modules=arrayOf(AppModule::class, AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class,
        SharedPrefModule::class, ActivityBuilder::class))
interface AppComponent {

    fun inject (app:App)

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {

        @BindsInstance
        fun application(context: Application): Builder

        fun build(): AppComponent
    }
}
```

App:

```
class App : Application(),HasActivityInjector {
    @Inject
    lateinit var activityInjector : DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity>

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        DaggerAppComponent.builder().build().inject(this)

    }

    override fun activityInjector(): AndroidInjector<Activity> = activityInjector
}
```

Activity:

```
class StartActivity: AppCompatActivity(), HasActivityInjector {

    @Inject
    lateinit var activityInjector : DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity>

    @Inject
    lateinit var sharedPref : SharedPreferences

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        AndroidInjection.inject(this)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.start_activity_layout)

//        var data = sharedPref.getString(SHARED_PREFERENCES_SETTINGS, "")
//        Log.d("tag", "data - $data")
    }

    override fun activityInjector(): AndroidInjector<Activity> = activityInjector
}
```

Comment: look at `SharedPreferences?` and look at `SharedPreferences` what is the difference

Answer (score 0):

SharedPrefModule uses Context in order to create a SharedPreferences instance, and since you are not including any module that provide a context Dagger might not be able to create a SharedPreferences instance.